# is it possible to use AVAudioRecorder alongwith MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudiorecorder

When a song from iPod chosen using MPMediaQuery is playing with MPMusicPlayerController, is it possible to record a clip of the song using AVAudioRecorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in any useful way.  The AVAudioRecorder uses device input, such as the phone mic or the headset mic.  You cannot route the audio played by MPMusicPlayerController into AVAudioRecorder in code.

Note that the MediaPlayer API also doesn't afford any access to raw samples or the source MP3/M4A/M4P files.

Comment: Is it possible to record from the headset using AVAudioRecorder while a song MPMusicPlayerController is playing?